# Sectionmark not responding well for headers of lstlistoflistings

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, listings

I use headers in my LateX report for all my sections. For `\section*{}`, I have to add a `\sectionmark{}` to make it work.
For some reason, it does not work well with `\lstlistoflistings` when I have two pages of listings that are listed.

Here is the relevant sample of my code (but some packages might be useless for this part):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} % set the \leftmark
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark} % 1. sectionname
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of Figures and Annexes}
\renewcommand*{\lstlistlistingname}{List of Annexes}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures and Annexes}
\vspace{15cm}
\sectionmark{List of Figures and Annexes}
\lstlistoflistings
\sectionmark{List of Figures and Annexes}

\pagebreak

\section*{Introduction}
\sectionmark{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
text
\pagebreak

\centering
\section*{Annexes}\label{sec:annex}
\sectionmark{\nameref{sec:annex}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:annex}}

\subsection*{Test}
\lstinputlisting{test.txt}
\subsection*{Test}
\lstinputlisting{test.txt}
\subsection*{Test}
\lstinputlisting{test.txt}
\subsection*{Test}
\lstinputlisting{test.txt}

\end{document}
```

I only added a `\vspace{15cm}` here to show what happen when a second page is created, without adding to much `test.txt` in this sample.
With this code, I obtain the result I am looking for with the Introduction section (page 3):

Here is what I get for page 1:
[image]

How can I make the header of page 1 become "List of Figures and Annexes" instead of "LIST OF ANNEXES"?

EDIT:
The answer of Christian Hupfer works perfectly for the previous code. Here is the long version of the example where the headers still disappear:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tocloft} % cftaddline
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[colorlinks = true,
            linkcolor = black,
            urlcolor  = blue,
            citecolor = black,
            anchorcolor = black]{hyperref}

\usepackage{vmargin}

\title{Title}
\author{Author} 

\makeatletter
\let\thetitle\@title
\let\theauthor\@author
\let\thedate\@date
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[R]{\theauthor} % predefined ()
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark} % 1. sectionname
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of Figures}
\renewcommand{\lstlistlistingname}{List of Annexes}
}

\begin{document}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section*{Acknowledgements}\label{sec:ackn}
\paragraph{} Text \\
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:ackn}}

\clearpage
\begin{abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
Text
\end{abstract}
\sectionmark{Abstract}

\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Contents}
\sectionmark{Contents}

\clearpage
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename}
\sectionmark{\listfigurename}

\clearpage
\lstlistoflistings
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\lstlistlistingname}
\sectionmark{\lstlistlistingname}

\clearpage
\section*{Introduction}
\sectionmark{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
text

\clearpage
\section{Section}
\paragraph{} Text

\clearpage
\section*{Conclusion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Conclusion}
\sectionmark{Conclusion}
Text

\clearpage
\begingroup
\centering
\section*{Annexes}\label{sec:annex}
\endgroup
\sectionmark{\nameref{sec:annex}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:annex}}
Text

\end{document}
```

I could correct it by deleting some package that were not mandatory for my report (as parskip) and the headers reappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some main causes for this problem:

- A missing `\clearpage` or (`\cleardoublepage`) after `\sectionmark` changes
- The changes to `\lstlistoflistings` etc. are not effective since the packages change it soon afterwards, i.e. the own definitions must be entered in a `\AtBeginDocument` - hook to 'guarantee' that those own settings will be used.

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}} % set the \leftmark
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark} % 1. sectionname
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}


\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of Figures and Annexes}
\renewcommand*{\lstlistlistingname}{List of Annexes}
}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename}%List of Figures and Annexes}
\sectionmark{\listfigurename}
\clearpage
\lstlistoflistings
\sectionmark{\lstlistlistingname}
\clearpage


\section*{Introduction}
\sectionmark{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\blindtext
\clearpage


\begingroup
\centering%?????

\section*{Annexes}\label{sec:annex}

\endgroup

\sectionmark{\nameref{sec:annex}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{sec:annex}}

\subsection*{Test}
\lstinputlisting{test.txt}
\subsection*{Test}
\lstinputlisting{test.txt}
\subsection*{Test}
\lstinputlisting{test.txt}
\subsection*{Test}
\lstinputlisting{test.txt}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is working for the short example. However, back in my whole report, the headings disappear for the page `\listoffigures` when I add some `\clearpage` instead of `\pagebreak` that I used previously.  Should I use another package?

Comment: @fidekild: Well, it's up to you then to provide a longer document.

Comment: I just added the longer example, with your solutions used in it.

Answer (score 0):

After adding some other packages required for my document, the same problem occurred again. It can be solved for good using `\nouppercase` that will force lower-case at the place desired. Here, for the header, it is solved with:

```
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
```